# Why is 'Ö'.localeCompare('Z') equal -1 instead of 1, if 'Ö' > 'Z'?

Tags: javascript, string

Why `console.log('Ö'.localeCompare('Z')); //-1` ?

If

> "str.localeCompare(str2):
> Returns a negative number if str is less than str2.
> Returns a positive number if str is greater than str2.
> Returns 0 if they are equivalent.

And

```
console.log('Ö' > 'Z'); // true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'Ö' > 'Z'` compares charcodes (indeed, 214 > 90)

`localeCompare` compares alphabetically (in most alphabets, 'Ö' precedes 'Z')

Comment: Further reading: [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) [`Intl.Collator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator/Collator)